# Redefining imported jinja macros

Tags: jinja2

Let's say I have this template with macros (these are simplified):

```
{# macros.html #}
{% macro a(opts = {}) %}
   {{ opts.a }}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro b(opts = {}) %}
   {{ opts.b }}
{% endmacro %}
```

and this one which contains the override

```
{# macros_override.html #}
{% macro a(opts = {}) %}
    Overridden: {{ opts.a }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And then I want to have a template with all these macros under the same namespace `macros`

```
{# template.html #}
{% import 'macros.html' as macros %}
{% import 'macros_override.html' as macros %}

{{ macros.a({ 'a': 'foo' }) }}
{{ macros.b({ 'b': 'bar' }) }}
```

and the output I expect:

```
Overridden: foo
bar
```

But `b` is undefined. I tried to change `macros_override.html` template to be like this:

```
{# macros_override.html #}
{% extends 'macros.html' %}
{% macro a(opts = {}) %}
    Overridden: {{ opts.a }}
{% endmacro %}
```

and then import only override template as macros but macro `a` isn't overridden in this case and I don't really know why.

Can I override imported macro in jinja through another import somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So with the help of my colleague, I figured it out.

> the parent template evaluated after the child one
>   http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#my-macros-are-overridden-by-something

that means if you want to use second option you just have to check the macro for existence in parent template.

Works like this:

```
{# macros.html #}
{% if not a %}
{% macro a(opts = {}) %}
   {{ opts.a }}
{% endmacro %}
{% endif %}

{% if not b %}
{% macro b(opts = {}) %}
   {{ opts.b }}
{% endmacro %}
{% endif %}
```

and this one which contains the override

```
{# macros_override.html #}
{% extends 'macros.html' %}
{% if not a %}{# I repeat here in case there's gonna be a double extend #}
{% macro a(opts = {}) %}
    Overridden: {{ opts.a }}
{% endmacro %}
{% endif %}
```

and the just import them like this

```
{# template.html #}
{% import 'macros_override.html' as macros %}

{{ macros.a({ 'a': 'foo' }) }}
{{ macros.b({ 'b': 'bar' }) }}
```

and it outputs as expected

```
Overridden: foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem where we wanted users to be able to override individual macros by extending a default template. Repeated `{% if not a %}` was a bit tedious here, so we fixed this with a Jinja2 extension:

```py
class DefaultMacroExtension(ext.Extension):
    """
    This extension provides a new `{% defaultmacro %}` statement, which defines a macro only if it does not exist.
    For example,

        {% defaultmacro example() %}
            test 123
        {% enddefaultmacro %}

    is equivalent to

        {% macro default_example() %}
        test 123
        {% endmacro %}
        {% if not example %}
            {% macro example() %}
                test 123
            {% endmacro %}
        {% endif %}

    The default implementation is also available as `default_$macroname`, which makes it possible
    to reference it in the override.
    """

    tags = {"defaultmacro"}

    def parse(self, parser):
        m = nodes.Macro(lineno=next(parser.stream).lineno)
        name = parser.parse_assign_target(name_only=True).name
        m.name = f"default_{name}"
        parser.parse_signature(m)
        m.body = parser.parse_statements(("name:enddefaultmacro",), drop_needle=True)

        if_stmt = nodes.If(
            nodes.Not(nodes.Name(name, "load")),
            [nodes.Macro(name, m.args, m.defaults, m.body)],
            [],
            [],
        )
        return [m, if_stmt]

env = Environment(
    extensions=[DefaultMacroExtension],
)
```